# printing progress for my application lag for Kafka stream application

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

is there any nice way to print the progresss in a kafka stream app? I feel that my app is falling behind and I want a nice way to show the progress of processing the events in my app

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, not within the Streams API.

You're more than welcome to import methods that `ConsumerGroupCommand.scala` uses to get the group lag and calculate / print from there.

Or you can externally install a tool like Burrow or Remora which have REST APIs for accessing lag information

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following class to help be print the lag/progress easily

```
package util;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.ListConsumerGroupOffsetsResult;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.ListOffsetsResult;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.OffsetSpec;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.*;
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Slf4j
public class LagLogger implements AutoCloseable {
    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    private String topic;
    private String consumerGroupName;
    private int logDelayInMilliSeconds;
    private Properties kafkaStreamsProperties;
    private boolean closed;
    private AdminClient adminClient;

    public LagLogger(String topic, String consumerGroupName, Properties kafkaStreamProperties, int logDelayInMilliSeconds) {
        this.topic = topic;
        this.kafkaStreamsProperties = kafkaStreamProperties;
        this.logDelayInMilliSeconds = logDelayInMilliSeconds;
        this.consumerGroupName = consumerGroupName;
        adminClient = AdminClient.create(LagLogger.this.kafkaStreamsProperties);
    }

    public class LagVisualizerTask implements AutoCloseable, Runnable {

        public LagVisualizerTask() {

        }

        public void run() {
            ListConsumerGroupOffsetsResult listConsumerGroupOffsetsResult = adminClient.listConsumerGroupOffsets(LagLogger.this.consumerGroupName);

            // Current offsets.
            Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> topicPartitionOffsetAndMetadataMap = null;
            try {
                topicPartitionOffsetAndMetadataMap = listConsumerGroupOffsetsResult.partitionsToOffsetAndMetadata().get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // all topic partitions.
            Set<TopicPartition> topicPartitions = topicPartitionOffsetAndMetadataMap.keySet();
            // list of end offsets for each partitions.
            ListOffsetsResult listOffsetsResult = adminClient.listOffsets(topicPartitions.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), tp -> OffsetSpec.latest())));

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.append(topic+": ");
            for (var entry : topicPartitionOffsetAndMetadataMap.entrySet()) {
                String finalString = stringBuilder.toString();
                if (entry.getKey().topic().equals(LagLogger.this.topic)) {
                    long current_offset = entry.getValue().offset();
                    long end_offset = 0;
                    try {
                        end_offset = listOffsetsResult.partitionResult(entry.getKey()).get().offset();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    stringBuilder.append(current_offset);
                    stringBuilder.append(" --> ");
                    stringBuilder.append(end_offset);
                    stringBuilder.append(" ("+String.format("%.2f", ((double)current_offset/end_offset)*100)   +"%)");
                    stringBuilder.append("    /    ");
                }
            }
            log.info(stringBuilder.toString());
        }

        public void close()  {
            closed = true;
        }
    }

    public LagVisualizerTask startNewLagVisualizerTask() {
        LagVisualizerTask lagVisualizerTask = new LagVisualizerTask();
        scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(lagVisualizerTask,0, LagLogger.this.logDelayInMilliSeconds, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        return lagVisualizerTask;
    }

    public void close() {
        if (scheduledExecutorService != null) {
            scheduledExecutorService.shutdownNow();
            scheduledExecutorService = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Which can be used as follows:

```
LagLogger lagVisualizer = new LagLogger(INPUT_TOPIC_NAME,APPLICATION_ID,configuration.getKafkaStreamsProperties(),DELY_BETWEEN_LOGS);
lagVisualizer.startNewLagVisualizerTask();
```